# AVPlayer sometimes doesn't load a video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a one button and AVPlayer. After button click I record a video using DBAttachmentPickerController and I want to load it to the AVPlayer.

In function below I try to load it:

```
func refresh(attachmentInfo: AttachmentInfo) {
        self.videoLayer.player = nil
        if let url = attachmentInfo.url {
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: url) // line A
                self.videoLayer.player = self.player // line B
        }
}
```

In 6/10 cases it works fine, but sometimes the video doesn't load to AVPlayer.

When I set breakpoints in line A and B it works always.

Any ideas?

Comment: Curious if you found a solution for this?

Comment: Oh man :D Thanks but I've worked since 3 months as Java Dev in new place :)

Answer (score 1):

I also hit this exact issue as yours. In my case the `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` were inside tableview cells which made the problem worse. However, I was using an API which returned the actual video URL, and an Image URL which consisted of the video's first frame's image. In the tableview cell logic, I first attempt to load the video into `AVPlayer` and then check if the `AVPlayer` has any `.video` assets, if it didn't then I simply load the Image from the other URL into the `UIView` (using a `UIImageView` of course) with a "Play" button image in the center of the Image. When the user taps the play button the selector function should try to load the `AVPlayer` again with the video URL. If the video loads and `AVPlayer` has assets then `play()` else simply `return` (and possibly alert the user that the video can't be loaded).

If you do not have the image of the first frame of the video, you can simply use a placeholder image and a button.

The way to check if the `player` has a video or not-

```
if player.currentItem?.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).count == 0{
   print("Oops! no video here")
   //load an image, and add a button here
}else{
   //do whatever needs to be done if video is available
}
```

Unfortunately, there isn't much else that can be done here unless you have some solid networking code where in you can download the video in a `utility` thread and store it in cache, but then again you have to be cognizant about the user's data usage, spawning too many download threads etc.

For image caching in the `UITableView` cell, I used `SDWebImage` [library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) from Github so that I can be (somewhat) assured that my image (for the video) atleast would be cached in case of bad/slow network, or network interruptions.

Comment: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).count is always Zero for the HLS, any solution getting list of bitrates for HLS